# Dvorak SIP is not shown in some devices like Pidion

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, soft-keyboard, dvorak, soft-input-panel

I have built and deployed `Dvorak SIP` sample from `C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\PocketPC\CPP\ATL\dvoraksip` location.  The sample successfully deploys and registers and when I click on Dvorak from the SIP icon at the middle of the tray it is opened in `Windows Mobile 5 emulator` and some other devices except [Pidion BIP-1300-GSM](http://www.mypidion.com/product/product_tab.asp?t_idx=178&bmenu=1) which is running Windows Mobile 5.0.

What is the reason?

I should mention that it is always deployed and registered successfully.

**UPDATE**

I put `DebugMessage` in all of the methods.

When I Deploy `Dvorak`, methods in `dvoraksip.cpp` are called on device like what happens on Emulator.

When I click the icon in tray in Emulator methods in `dvorak_implementation.cpp` are called correctly but nothing is called on Pidion device.

Comment: To find out the cause you should add some DEBUGMSG to the code and watch the debugger when you run the Dvorak SIP DLL.

Comment: Is the pidion running windows mobile 5 or CE 5?

Comment: @josef It is running Windows Mobile 5.0

Comment: I assume the SIP did not register correctly. When you deployed the SIP (a DLL) to Windows dir! you need to register it. After registration you should reboot.Ensure the UID is unique.

Comment: @josef  I have registered it. I checked the registry. The registry values are same in Device and Emulator. But keyboard is shown in Emulator and is not shown in Device.

Comment: To better understand what is not working with this ATL sample code which creates a DLL I would write a tester app that loads the DLL and calls the exported functions like IInputMethod::GetImData, IInputMethod::SetImData, IInputMethod::UserOptionsDlg . If you are looking for writing a custom SIP you can use Richard Boling's SIP example (http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/5461b.aspx) that does not use ATL. BTW: is the VC runtime installed on the device? You will find, when you try to load the DLL in a test app.

Answer (score 1):

I don know what possibly went wrong on your side. There are some pitfalls when using this WM653 sample on Windows Mobile 5. When you switch to WM5 in VS8 configuration manager, the deployment settings have to been adjusted:

[image: deploy settings for DVORAK SIP]

Do you have WM5 SDK installed within VS2008 too?

In VS8 ensure that you link ATL statically:
[image: ATL static linked]

Here is my updated VS2008 project/solution of DVORAK SIP sample using WM5 SDK: http://www.hjgode.de/temp/dvoraksipVS2008_WM5SDK.zip

I tested that on a WM5 device (no Pidion, an Intermec CK60 running WM5):
[image: Dvorak SIP on WM5 device screen]

I have seen that you posted the same question at social.msdn and who knows where too. If the pidion still does not work like a WM5 device, you should consider changing the model.

As an alternative you may use Richard Boling's NumPanel example of a SIP.

[image: Richard Boling Nummeric Keypad SIP example]

Here is the VS8 solution for WM5SDK: http://www.hjgode.de/temp/BolingNumPanel.zip

Comment: I followed your instructions and nothing changed :(

Comment: Is the problem related to CLSID? in the sample it is `{42429695-AE04-11D0-A4F8-00AA00A749B9}`

Comment: The CLSID or GUID has to be unique. You can create your own, new GUID using VS tools. Does the NumPanel show on the pidion?

Comment: I tested your sample. It is shown in both emulator 5 and 6 but is not shown in my device. Pidion does not show Dvorak, Your keypad and my custom keyboard :(